# Wordpress Query orderby title with UTF8 string in title

Tags: query

I got posts with titles are in utf8 encoding.

When I query posts with `orderby` is `title`, those with utf8 characters at the beginning are at the end.

Example: post title starts with `Đ` are at the end of the list.

Is there anyway I can make orderby order sorts `Đ`right after `D`?

Comment: What is the encoding on your database tables-- the collation?

Comment: it's `utf8_general_ci`